# "Choose folder" dialog in document library reacts really slow

Tags: document-library, performance, folder

While uploading a document into a library I want to choose in which folder the document should be uploaded.

When I choose a folder the PickerTreeView.aspx answers really slow.

[Example image where the PickerTreeView answers really slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwP4n.png)

In this example i've openend a folder with 65 subfolders.
The second request is the "click" on the folder I want to choose ("BA-EDV") and it also need's more than 30 seconds.

Do you have some advice for me how to speed things up or an explanation why it's so slow?